# Duplicating Entries On Subsequent Months

Tags: javascript, duplicates, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Weird one.  Have two school building calendars being fed by public Google Cal.  Can click month-to-month without error, but when I hide one building cal and click to the next month, I end up with duplicate entries that continue to double then triple and continue duping as you click month to month.  Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
<link type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.woostercityschools.org/sites/woostercityschools.org/files/favicon_wcs.png" rel="shortcut icon">
<link type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.woostercityschools.org/sites/woostercityschools.org/files/favicon_wcs.png" rel="icon">
<script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/gcal.js"></script>
<script>
    var allCals = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'High School',
            url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/CALENDAR_ID_HERE@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
            color: '#0057b8',
            visible: true
        },{
            id: 2,
            name: 'Middle School',
            url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/CALENDAR_ID_HERE@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
            color: '#4b4c4c',
            visible: true
        }
    ];

    var gCals = function(){
        var ret = $.grep(allCals, function(a){
            return a.visible === true;
        });
        console.log('called gCals()');
        console.log(ret);       
        return ret;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Hide/Show all
        $('#hide-all').click(function(){
            $('.calendar-list button').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('btn-calendar-hide');
            });

            $.each(allCals, function(index,value){
                //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', this);
                this.visible = false;
            });

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        });

        $('#show-all').click(function(){
            $('.calendar-list button').each(function(){
                $(this).addClass('btn-calendar-hide');
            });
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $.each(allCals, function(index,value){
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', allCals[index]);
                this.visible = true;
            });
        });

        //Populate buttons
        $.each( allCals, function( index, value ){
            var tmp = $('<button/>', {
                    type: 'button',
                    class: 'btn btn-block btn-calendar',
                    style: 'background-color: '+value.color,
                    text: value.name,
                    id: 'btn_calendar'+value.id,
                    click: function () {                        
                        if ($(this).hasClass('btn-calendar-hide')){
                            //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', value);
                            $( this ).removeClass('btn-calendar-hide');
                            value.visible = false;
                        } else {
                            //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', value);
                            $( this ).addClass('btn-calendar-hide');
                            value.visible = true;                           
                        }
                        updateCalendar();
                    }      
                });
            if (value.visible === true){
                tmp.addClass('btn-calendar-hide');
            }
            $('.calendar-list').append(
                tmp
            );
        });

        //Display the calendar
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDiJjIhfkuYrKzwrj0GS3wBN1erVcMsJmM',
            eventSources: allCals,
            eventClick: function(event) {
                // opens events in a popup window
                window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
                return false;
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            },
            header: {
                left: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            }
        });

        function updateCalendar(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $.each(allCals, function(index,value){
                if (value.visible === true){
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', allCals[index]);
                }
            });
        }

    });

</script>
<style>
a.fc-event:hover, a.fc-event:focus{
    color:#000;
}
#loading {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    width:96%;
    padding:10px;
    z-index:999;
    border: solid 1px #f8e166;
    margin:1% 2%;
}
#loading h3 {
    margin:2%;
}
#calendar {
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.btn {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.btn-calendar {
    background-image: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.btn-calendar-hide {
    opacity: 1;
}
.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media print {
a[href]:after {
    content: none;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loading" class="bg-warning">
  <h3 class="text-center">Loading...</h3>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-print"> <a href="http://www.woostercityschools.org/hs"><img class="img-responsive center-block" style="margin-top:2em; margin-bottom:2em" src="logo-district.jpg" alt="Wooster City Schools" ></a>
      <div class="calendar-list">
        <h4>Calendars
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="show-all" type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Show All</button>
            <button id="hide-all" type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Hide All</button>
          </div>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <p class="text-right hidden-print" style="margin-top:2%"><a href="javascript:print();" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Print</a></p>
      <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is that calling `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');` deletes the events currently visible on the calendar, but it doesn't remove the *source* of those events.

That means that when you then go on to call `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource'` next, you are simply adding the same source of events over and over again. Next time you press "next" or "previous" to change the date range, this triggers fullCalendar to request new events for that date range from all the available sources. Since you haven't removed any sources, but have kept adding more, you can see how this then leads to duplication of events in the display.

In one part of your code you've commented out a call to `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource'` ...but actually that (or the plural "removeEventSources", where appropriate) should be the correct approach. If you remove the source then it will both remove the existing events and also prevent future requests to that source from adding more events again.